# ImportError: cannot import name CompletionFinder

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu "14.04.1", with python version 2.7.6

I have installed `python-argcomplete` package (version 0.6.9-1) but still getting an error while importing CompletionFinder from argComplete.

This is import line in my code:

```
from argcomplete import CompletionFinder
```

While compiling this file I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name CompletionFinder
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried importing `argcomplete` and then using `CompletionFinder` as `argcomplete.CompletionFinder`. Try and see if you get error

Comment: yes i did. but i am getting error in import statement itself, which is:                                          "rom argcomplete import CompletionFinder"

Comment: What is the error in this case? you can also check if this package is installed or not on your device using this command: `pip list | grep argcomplete`

Comment: package is installed on the system. i also mentioned the version in my previous post. here is the output of pip command:                                         pip list | grep argcomplete
argcomplete (0.6.9)

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.6.9 in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories doesn't have the `CompletionFinder` class, it was introduced in version 0.8.0 according to GitHub.

`CompletionFinder` is almost identical to the `autocomplete` function, so you might get away with just using that.

Another solution might be to uninstall the package and get the latest version from PyPI with the following command:

```
sudo pip install argcomplete
```

Comment: version 0.8.0 of argcomplete is not available yet. i updated my python version from 2.7 to Python3 and it fixed the issue. Thanks for directing.